# Function / Class as Angular service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I am trying to inject a paging service on Angular controllers so I have:

```
angular.module("app").factory("paging", paging);

function paging() {  

  var paging = function (pageNumber, pageSize, itemCount) {    
    this.itemCount = itemCount;
    this.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.pageCount = itemCount > 0 ? Math.ceil(itemCount / pageSize) : 0;
  }

  paging.prototype.itemCount = 1
  paging.prototype.pageCount = 1
  paging.prototype.pageNumber = 1   
  paging.prototype.pageSize = 1

  paging.prototype.isFirst = function () {
    return this.pageNumber === 1; 
  }

  paging.prototype.toFirst() = function () {
    this.pageNumber = 1;
  }

  return paging;

}
```

I keep getting the error "paging.prototype.toFirst is not a function".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the parentheses don't belong? `paging.prototype.toFirst = function() ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is throwing an error because you are calling `toFirst` function before creating it, Rather I can say its syntactical mistake. You should creating function rather than calling it.

```
paging.prototype.toFirst = function () {
    this.pageNumber = 1;
}
```

Comment: Of course! I didn't even notice the () after the toFirst ... ai ai ai. Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel no problem..that happens.. Thanks :-)